# On pressing tab key the page does not scroll up due to fixed bottom footer

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout, footer

I have a long form in a webpage. There is a fixed footer with z-index:999 at the bottom. When I press tab and move from one field to another, then at the bottom of the page the focus goes on fields that are hidden behind the footer. The page does not scroll up for these fields. Once the focus goes below these fields then the page is scrolled up ( as is logical ). But is there a way to scroll up the page when the focus is on the fields that are hidden behind the fixed footer?[The issue is demonstrated in the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVFyS.jpg)

```
.footer {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f5f5f5;
border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
bottom: 0;
height: 45px;
left: 0% !important;
line-height: 40px;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
text-align: center;
width: 100% !important;
z-index: 999;
}
```

Updated field names in JSFiddle for better understanding: https://jsfiddle.net/2hgo3zo1/3/

I have updated the jsfiddle so that field labels are different. Once I open the fiddle, the focus is on email address field, and password 1 textbox is visible on my screen. Steps to replicate my issue:

1. Focus is on Email address field. I start pressing tab.
2. When I reach password 1 textbox, I press tab again.
3. The focus is on the textbox of Email address 2. But the textbox is not visible.
4. Now type 'abc' (without pressing tab)
5. Press Tab again the password 2 textbox is in focus and now the page scrolled up on its own.
6. Please notice that Email address 2 field has text abc though the textbox was not visible.
7. Now what i want is that the page scrolls when the focus is on textbox of Email address 2 (this is not scrolling up automatically as the fixed footer is not considered in page height.)

Comment: Code please....

Comment: @Vishnu Added the CSS.

Comment: pls add html & css codes to snippet or https://jsfiddle.net/  otherwise we can't find the problem

Comment: @Vishnu - Added JSFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching for days, and using the jQuery posted by @ChanderShekhar, the final script block that worked perfectly for me is given below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('input, button, a, textarea, span').focus(function () {
    var footerHeight = 120; //footerHeight = footer height + element height + buffer
    var element = jQuery(this);
    if (element.offset().top - (jQuery(window).scrollTop()) > 
         (jQuery(window).height() - footerHeight)) {
        jQuery('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: element.offset().top - (jQuery(window).height() - footerHeight)
        }, 500);
     }
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 
 $("input").keydown(function (e) {
   if (e.which == 9){
    var center = $(window).height()/2;
    var top = $(this).offset().top ;
    if (top > center)
        $(window).scrollTop(top-center);
  }
 });
 });
```

```css
.footer {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f5f5f5;
border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
bottom: 0;
height: 45px;
left: 0% !important;
line-height: 40px;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
text-align: center;
width: 100% !important;
z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
 <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active">
           <a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
 </div>
 </nav>
  <div>
    <div class="container" style="padding-top: 80px; padding-bottom: 50px;">
      <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
          <input autofocus="" type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address 1</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password 1</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address 2</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password 2</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address 3</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password 3</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address 4</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password 4</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address 5</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword2">Password 5</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
          <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
          <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
          </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="footer">
    Fixed footer
   </div>
```

Comment: Please try it with jquery i found it on stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks @ChanderShekhar, this worked, but to some extent. In full screen form, the page was unnecessarily scrolling up for the fields in the second half of the page. Though the fields were already visible.

Answer (score 0):

Please try padding-bottom: 45px; in body tag

Comment: padding-bottom is already there. That works when the page is scrolled till bottom. But the page is not at bottom yet.

Answer (score 0):

@Izafa check this answer, in your fiddle i cannot find the problem like that scrnshot. Anyway you can try to put the top and footer divs in different classes:

```css
.topDiv {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.footer {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f5f5f5;
border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
bottom: 0;
height: 45px;
left: 0% !important;
line-height: 40px;
position: fixed;
right: 0;
text-align: center;
width: 100% !important;
z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="topDiv">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
 <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a href="#">Brand</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active">
           <a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
 </div>
 </nav>
  <div>
    <div class="container" style="padding-top: 80px; padding-bottom: 50px;">
      <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
          <input autofocus="" type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputPassword2">Password</label>
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
          <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
          <p class="help-block">Example block-level help text here.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox"> Check me out
          </label>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

 <div class="footer">
    Fixed footer
   </div>
```

Comment: Please see the edited answer above to know the steps of understanding my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Add this script in your script file, This will give you more reliable and accurate solution thanks, and do rate my solution.

```
$('input').focus(function() {
var ele = $(this);
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: ele.offset().top - 80
}, 800);
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I actually used the provided [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45176179/5271220) but made some changes to it.

I was using bootstrap-select which required me to change the event handler but more importantly I didnt like the UX caused by the scrolling up when a user clicked a field higher on the page.

This caused an awkward back and forth motion as you tabbed/clicked fields as it tried to force the field to a specific location in the view via the scroll. Typically that location was the bottom of the page based on the footerHeight, so going back to a higher field put it back at the bottom.

This option will scroll up if they tab to something out of view using the inherent browser positioning which was fine with me.

```
if ($('div.activate-auto-scroll').length) {
    $(document).on('focus', 'input, button, a, textarea, span, select', function () {
        var footerHeight = 300; //footerHeight = footer height + element height + buffer
        var element = $(this);
        var formPosition = element.offset().top;
        var viewableArea = $(window).height() - footerHeight;
        var screenPosition = this.getBoundingClientRect().top;
        var scrollDestination = formPosition - viewableArea;

        if (formPosition > viewableArea && screenPosition > formPosition - scrollDestination) {  // second conditional stops it from scrolling up and causing the page to force fields to the bottom
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: scrollDestination
            }, 500);
        }
    });
}
```